# What is the first non-Constitution class Starfleet ship we see in canon?

Tags: star-trek, spaceship

In *TOS*, we follow the journeys of the *USS Enterprise*, a *Constitution* class starship.  I recall in *TOS* that we encounter a few other Starfleet starships, but from memory all of these are also *Constitution* class.  My question then is **what is the first Starfleet ship we see in canon that isn't a *Constitution* class vessel?**

In terms of 'first', I mean out-of-universe, as in following the chronology of the production of series (i.e. *TOS* comes first, then *TNG*, *DS9*, *VOY*, *ENT* - not *TAS* because that isn't considered canon)

Comment: I assume you only want the originally broadcast version of the original series, not the remastered version with some new CG graphics? In the remastered version of "Charlie X" the USS Anteres, which was named but not shown in the original version, was displayed in a brief shot shown on [this page](http://www.ex-astris-scientia.org/articles/antares.htm).

Comment: @Hypnosifl yes sorry. I'm more interested in the out of universe development of starships but still an excellent find!

Comment: http://www.ex-astris-scientia.org/articles/tos_ships.htm

Comment: @Richard none of those other than the Enterprise are Starfleet ships though

Comment: @TheDoc - Indeed. That was my point

Comment: are you looking for a picture, cause they mention a few other ships ealier.

Comment: Deleted my answer about the automated freighters in _More Tribbles, More Troubles_ when I realized that TAS mean The Animated Series.

Comment: By the way, if you are primarily interested in the artistic development of Starfleet starships, you might consider modifying the question to only include original designs, rather than existing non-Starfleet designs which were just renamed as Starfleet ships (and perhaps superficially modified) to save money as in the answers by me and Himarm. There are also some Starfleet ship designs that were drawn but not used in the production of the original show, then finally used for the design of "historical" ships in TNG or one of the later shows, but I guess that's beyond the scope of the question.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Looking at the list of original series ships on [this page](http://www.ex-astris-scientia.org/articles/tos_ships.htm), a non-Constitution freighter called the [*Woden*](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Woden) was shown in the episode "The Ultimate Computer" from season 2 of the original series (predating the "Way to Eden" ship in Himarm's answer, which was from season 3), and was probably Starfleet given the registration of NCC-325.* Unfortunately in design terms it isn't very interesting--the production crew just reused the [*Botany Bay*](http://www.ex-astris-scientia.org/schematics/dy100-screen.jpg) (a pre-Starfleet ship) from "Space Seed".

[image]

*After looking at the [transcript](http://www.chakoteya.net/StarTrek/53.htm) of this episode, I see NCC-325 is not mentioned in the dialogue, so its possible this registration is only seen on the new CG version for the remastered show, and wasn't present on the original model. The dialogue does say the *Woden* is "Listed in Starfleet Registry as an old-style ore freighter converted to automation", but I don't think it's clear that any ship listed in Starfleet Registry must have an NCC registration number.

Comment: I think we have a winner!

Answer (score 7):

> The Aurora (NC-17740) was a 23rd century Federation Class J space
> cruiser. (TOS: "The Way to Eden" 03X20)

This is the Current version of the ship Via remastered CGI.
[image]

I verified that this episode did include this ship on screen, Via Netflix.

This is the original version most likely seen on TV.

[image]

[Memory Alpha](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Aurora_(NC-17740))

> Starfleet maintained an old class J starship for use as a cadet training vessel. During an inspection by Fleet Captain Pike, a baffle plate ruptured, exposing the crew to harmful delta rays. Pike received an extremely high dose which ultimately left him an invalid, as he went in to rescue the cadets. (TOS: "The Menagerie, Part I")

They appear to be an old model'd ship, that starfleet kept around to use as a training ship.

Comment: I think there may be a distinction of Federation / Starfleet here...

Comment: @ChrisB.Behrens starfleet=federation in TOS.

Comment: If The Doc is interested in design history, [this page](http://www.ex-astris-scientia.org/articles/tos_ships.htm) notes that the version of the *Aurora* from the original broadcast was actually a re-used [Tholian ship](http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Tholian_starship_(23rd_century)) with warp nacelles added to it.

Comment: @Himarm No, StarFleet has always been a separate organization. In the Enterprise series time, StarFleet existed and the Federation did not yet exist. Once the Federation was organized, StarFleet became a branch operating under the Federation flag.

Comment: @BBlake yes, and this question is based on TOS, starfleet is the Ship portion  or fleet portion, of the Federation. so they are synonymous for this question.

Comment: I would disagree. A Ticonderoga class cruiser and a Merchant Marine cargo ship are both US flagged ships, but only the Ticonderoga is a US Navy ship. In the same way, the Aurora class vessel is a Federation star ship, but it is not a StarFleet vessel.

Comment: @BBlake - But the US Navy is a military organization, so aren't Merchant Marine ships excluded bc they aren't primarily for use in military operations? (which includes logistical support, but not ordinary trade) Whereas Starfleet is called on to serve military functions, but it is not primarily a military organization, so starships of any function can be part of Starfleet. I wouldn't rule out the idea of Federation ships which are not part of Starfleet, but I don't think the analogy with the Navy gives good reason to think this would be the most logical way for vessels to be divided up.

Comment: Cc @BBlake if evidence can be found to support the idea that this class of starship has served in Starfleet then this answer would meet the criteria of the question

Comment: Looking at the transcript of "The Way to Eden" [here](http://www.chakoteya.net/StarTrek/75.htm), and doing keyword searches using command-F (that's on my Mac, you can do control-F on a PC), it doesn't seem like the *Aurora* is ever referred to as "Class J" in the dialogue, nor is it even 100% clear whether the "stolen space cruiser" is the property of the Federation or the Catullans (it was stolen by the Catullan ambassador's son and his friends during treaty negotiations between the Federation and Catullans).

Answer (score 5):

I'm gonna go with the *USS Reliant* - Miranda class starship that we see in *Star Trek II: Wrath of Khan*

[image: The Miranda-class *USS Reliant*]

Answer (score 1):

The *Antares*, in Charlie X, the second aired episode of The Original Series, is a cargo ship.
[image]

Comment: A good answer, but it was discussed in the comments to the question and disqualified since it was only in remastered versions of the episode.

Answer (score -2):

IMHO it is perfectly possible that the *Constellation* in "The Doomsday Machine" was a starship of a non *Constitution* class.

When they search for the missing starship *Constellation* Spock says:

> I have it on the sensors, Captain. By configuration, a starship stopped in space. She appears to be drifting.

[1]http://www.chakoteya.net/StarTrek/35.htm

Note that Spock doesn't say that the configuration matches any particular CLASS of spacecraft.  He says that it matches a TYPE of spacecraft, a starship.

A TYPE of craft is one which performs a specific function, such as a battleship, an aircraft carrier, a tugboat, a private jet, a news helicopter, an airliner, a moon lander, etc.

A CLASS of craft is a group of craft of a specific TYPE which are all built to almost totally the same plans with only very minor variations.

The *Iowa* class battleships were one of dozens of classes of battleships which were built, for example.

So in Kirk''s era the Starfleet TYPE of starships has at least one CLASS, the *Constitution* class, and there may be several other classes of starships.  Thus identifying a ship as being of the starship TYPE may not necessarily identify it as being of the *Constitution* CLASS of starship.

I have read that a consumer model kit of the *Enterprise*  was used to film the  *Constellation* and that it was not totally accurate and there were slight differences in configuration.  When they look for the auxillery control room on the *Constellation* Kirk walks right past it before spotting Matt Decker in it.  So some of the internal arrangements are different on the *Constellation*.

Thus it is uncertain whether the differences between the *Enterprise* and the *Constellation* are differences between two different ships of the same TYPE and the same CLASS, or between two ships of the the same TYPE but different CLASSES.

Furthermore, nobody knows the "frame story" which explains how knowledge of future, 23rd century, events was transmitted to the creators of *Star Trek* in the 1960s.  And without knowing the "frame story", nobody can know how much of *Star Trek* is accurate.

Thus, so far as we can know, it is perfectly possible that the creators of *Star Trek* saved special effects money by deliberately making other starships seen in TOS look like *Constitution* class starships even though they knew those ships belonged to different classes.

So the common opinion that all starships seen in TOS were *Constitution* class starships is perfectty possible but has insufficient supporting evidence.  And this I suggest that the *Constellation* MIGHT POSSIBLY have been the first non *Constitution* class starship seen in TOS.

Comment: It's widely accepted that the USS Constellation was a Constitution Class, especially the [production list](http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Constitution_class#Footnotes) which indicated as much

Comment: The Doc - But when the creators were working on the list it was a list of starships, not a list of starships of a particular class.   Thus it is perfectly possible that some of the starships on the eventual list were starships of other classes.  Note that 12 or 13 or even a few more starships seem very few for Starfleet.  I suspect that TOS era starhips are a very rare type that combines all the power of the largest heavy cruisers in the defense branch of Starfleet with the laboratories of the largest science vessels in the research branch of Starfleet.